# inArray not returning true when value matches array object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to check if an input exists in an array and I keep getting the output to show false even when the input definitely matches an object in the array. Am I missing something?

```js
var name = $(".name").val();
var nameArray = ["Mary", "John"]

$(".submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function nameExists(name) {
    if ($.inArray(name, nameArray) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  console.log(nameExists());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="name">
  <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're not passing a name when you call `nameExists()`

Comment: Pass in the 'name' parameter into the function from the call on `nameExists()` or move this line `var name = $(".name").val();` inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're setting `name` when the page is first loaded, not when the user submits the form.
2. You're not passing the `name` variable to the function when you call it.

```js
var nameArray = ["Mary", "John"]

$(".submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function nameExists(name) {
    if ($.inArray(name, nameArray) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  var name = $(".name").val();
  console.log(nameExists(name));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="name">
  <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This solved it. Thanks for the quick response @Barmar